# Commutative axiom in vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

With $$u, \space v \in (E,+,\cdot); \space a \in R$$ where E is a vector space in the real numbers, addition is defined as: $$u+v = u-v$$ and the multiplication as $$a\cdot u = (-a) \cdot u$$ How can I prove the commutative axiom $$u+v = v+u$$ in addition?

Comment: What is $E{}{}$?

Comment: A vector space. I will edit the O.P

Comment: Apparently, we need $u-v=u+v=v+u=v-u$, so (being careful not to mix up the two additions) $2u=2v$. So this works only if either $E$ is zero-dimensional, or $2=0$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen My guess is that $R$ means $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I didn't check the LaTeX code for the real numbers, my bad.

Comment: having a multiplication on a vector space $E$ converts it into an algebra

Comment: @janmarqz what does that mean?

Comment: something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_over_a_field but in your case $(E,+,\cdot)$ you aren't defining $\cdot$ among vectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't: $u-v\neq v-u$, unless $u=v$.

Comment: Sorry for the tangent question, but under the same conditions if we are to prove that $$(u+v)+w = u+(v+w)$$ can we say that $$(u+v)+w = (u-v)-w$$ because $$u-v$$ forms a new vector in the vector space?

Comment: No. But we can say that $(u+v)+w=(u-v)-w$ because of how $+$ is defined in this context.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.